# Python encoding for pipe.communicate

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, subprocess, popen

I'm calling `pipe.communicate` from Python's [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module from Python 2.6. I get the following error from this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen

pipe = Popen(cwd)

pipe.communicate( data )
```

For an arbitrary `cwd`, and where `data` that contains unicode (specifically 0xE9):

```
Exec. exception: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 507: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):  

... stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate( data )

  File
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py",
line 671, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)

  File
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py",
line 1177, in _communicate
    bytes_written = os.write(self.stdin.fileno(), chunk)
```

This is happening, I presume, because `pipe.communicate()` is expecting ASCII encoded string, but `data` is unicode.

Is this the problem I'm encountering, and i sthere a way to pass unicode to `pipe.communicate()`?

Thank you for reading!

Brian

Comment: What do you mean by "contains Unicode"?  Specifically, 0xE9 is not, by itself, a valid Unicode code point in any common encoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I *may* have solved this by changing:

```
pipe.communicate( data )
```

to

```
pipe.communicate( data.encode('utf8') )
```

Though I stand to be corrected!

Brian

Comment: That's right.  Pipes (and files, sockets, etc.) transmit bytes, not Unicode (which is "characters").  You have to encode Unicode to transmit it.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed an issue I was having with Django - one of my forms is passed to an external processor via subprocess, and Unicode submissions kept failing until this was changed.